# Failed to create a docker container of topotest-frr

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, virtual-machine, ubuntu-18.04

I tried to make a docker container of frr with topotest running frr-topotests.sh, but i get the following error (it is at the end of the quote):

```
    latest: Pulling from frrouting/topotests
Digest: sha256:0d5ce5b3247f446416d13abfa2351dc0164424ea0ffe13fada02d6c8ce441dda
Status: Image is up to date for frrouting/topotests:latest
docker.io/frrouting/topotests:latest
=> Cleaning FRR builddir...
=> Syncing FRR source with host...
    281,387,541  99%  377.43MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#4347, to-chk=0/5036)   
    105,672,083  99%  319.92MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#3088, to-chk=0/3608)   
=> Building FRR...
libtoolize: putting auxiliary files in '.'.
libtoolize: copying file './ltmain.sh'
libtoolize: putting macros in AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS, 'm4'.
libtoolize: copying file 'm4/libtool.m4'
libtoolize: copying file 'm4/ltoptions.m4'
libtoolize: copying file 'm4/ltsugar.m4'
libtoolize: copying file 'm4/ltversion.m4'
libtoolize: copying file 'm4/lt~obsolete.m4'
configure.ac:164: installing './compile'
configure.ac:25: installing './config.guess'
configure.ac:25: installing './config.sub'
configure.ac:100: installing './install-sh'
configure.ac:100: installing './missing'
Makefile.am: installing './depcomp'
configure.ac: installing './ylwrap'
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... mawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... (cached) yes
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether gcc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of gcc... gcc3
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for g++... g++
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of g++... gcc3
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C99... none needed
checking for pkg-config... (cached) /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking minix/config.h usability... no
checking minix/config.h presence... no
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
checking whether gcc supports -diag-error 10006... no
checking whether gcc supports -std=gnu11... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu11 supports -fno-omit-frame-pointer... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu11 supports -funwind-tables... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu11 supports -Wall... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu11 supports -Wextra... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu11 supports -Wmissing-prototypes... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu11 supports -Wmissing-declarations... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu11 supports -Wpointer-arith... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu11 supports -Wbad-function-cast... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu11 supports -Wwrite-strings... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu11 supports -Wundef... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu11 supports -Wno-unused-result... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu11 supports -Wno-unused-parameter... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu11 supports -Wno-missing-field-initializers... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu11 supports -Wc++-compat... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu11 supports -diag-disable 3179... no
checking whether gcc -std=gnu11 supports -fplugin=tools/gcc-plugins/frr-format.so... no
checking whether gcc -std=gnu11 supports -fplugin=frr-format... no
checking if compiler needs -Werror to reject unknown flags... no
checking for the pthreads library -lpthreads... no
checking whether pthreads work without any flags... no
checking whether pthreads work with -Kthread... no
checking whether pthreads work with -kthread... no
checking for the pthreads library -llthread... no
checking whether pthreads work with -pthread... yes
checking for joinable pthread attribute... PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE
checking if more special flags are required for pthreads... no
checking for PTHREAD_PRIO_INHERIT... yes
checking for library containing pthread_condattr_setclock... none required
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for ar... ar
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... sed
checking for fgrep... /bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by gcc -std=gnu11... /usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm -B
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm -B) interface... BSD nm
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
checking how to convert x86_64-pc-linux-gnu file names to x86_64-pc-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert x86_64-pc-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... objdump
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for archiver @FILE support... @
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from gcc -std=gnu11 object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for a working dd... /bin/dd
checking how to truncate binary pipes... /bin/dd bs=4096 count=1
checking for mt... no
checking if : is a manifest tool... no
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if gcc -std=gnu11 supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
checking for gcc -std=gnu11 option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if gcc -std=gnu11 PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu11 static flag -static works... no
checking if gcc -std=gnu11 supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if gcc -std=gnu11 supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the gcc -std=gnu11 linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
checking for ld used by g++... /usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64
checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) is GNU ld... yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... no
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... (cached) GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether ar supports D option... yes
checking whether ranlib supports D option... yes
checking json-c/json.h usability... yes
checking json-c/json.h presence... yes
checking for json-c/json.h... yes
checking for json_object_get in -ljson-c... yes
checking python interpreter python3... not working
checking python interpreter python3.10... not working
checking python interpreter python3.9... not working
checking python interpreter python3.8... not working
checking python interpreter python3.7... not working
checking python interpreter python3.6... not working
checking python interpreter python3.5... not working
checking python interpreter python3.4... not working
checking python interpreter python3.3... not working
checking python interpreter python3.2... not working
checking python interpreter python... /usr/bin/python (python2)
checking whether /usr/bin/python-config is available... yes
checking whether /usr/bin/python-config provides a working build environment... yes
checking whether /usr/bin/python module pytest is available... yes
checking whether /usr/bin/python module sphinx is executable... yes
checking if zebra should be configurable to send Route Advertisements... yes
checking for objcopy... objcopy
checking for .interp value to use... /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
checking stropts.h usability... yes
checking stropts.h presence... yes
checking for stropts.h... yes
checking sys/ksym.h usability... no
checking sys/ksym.h presence... no
checking for sys/ksym.h... no
checking linux/version.h usability... yes
checking linux/version.h presence... yes
checking for linux/version.h... yes
checking asm/types.h usability... yes
checking asm/types.h presence... yes
checking for asm/types.h... yes
checking stdatomic.h usability... yes
checking stdatomic.h presence... yes
checking for stdatomic.h... yes
checking whether _Atomic qualifier works... yes
checking for pthread_np.h... no
checking for pthread_setname_np... yes
checking for pthread_set_name_np... no
checking for pthread_getthreadid_np... no
checking for Linux futex() support... yes
checking for net/if_var.h... no
checking for netinet/in_var.h... no
checking for net/if_dl.h... no
checking for net/netopt.h... no
checking for inet/nd.h... no
checking for netinet/ip_icmp.h... yes
checking for sys/sysctl.h... yes
checking for sys/sockio.h... no
checking for sys/conf.h... no
checking for ucontext.h... yes
checking for ucontext_t.uc_mcontext.uc_regs... no
checking for ucontext_t.uc_mcontext.regs... no
checking for ucontext_t.uc_mcontext.gregs... yes
checking which operating system interface to use... Linux
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... no
checking whether byte ordering is bigendian... no
checking for strlcat... no
checking for strlcpy... no
checking for getgrouplist... yes
checking for openat... yes
checking for unlinkat... yes
checking for posix_fallocate... yes
checking for main in -lreadline... yes
checking readline/history.h usability... yes
checking readline/history.h presence... yes
checking for readline/history.h... yes
checking for rl_completion_matches in -lreadline... yes
checking for append_history in -lreadline... yes
checking for library containing pow... -lm
checking for ppoll... yes
checking for pollts... no
checking asm-generic/unistd.h usability... yes
checking asm-generic/unistd.h presence... yes
checking for asm-generic/unistd.h... yes
checking whether __NR_setns is declared... yes
checking for setns... yes
checking net/bpf.h usability... no
checking net/bpf.h presence... no
checking for net/bpf.h... no
checking sys/dlpi.h usability... no
checking sys/dlpi.h presence... no
checking for sys/dlpi.h... no
checking zebra IS-IS I/O method... pfpacket
checking for struct ip_mreqn.imr_ifindex... yes
checking for linux/mroute.h... yes
checking for netinet/ip_mroute.h... no
checking for BSD struct ip_mreq hack... no
checking for RFC3678 protocol-independed API... yes
checking for net/if_media.h... no
checking for struct if_data.ifi_link_state... no
checking for netinet/tcp.h... yes
checking whether TCP_MD5SIG is declared... yes
checking for crypt in -lcrypt... yes
checking for res_init in -lresolv... no
checking for CARES (libcares)... yes
checking for struct utsname.domainname... yes
checking for netinet6/in6.h... no
checking for netinet/in6_var.h... no
checking for netinet6/in6_var.h... no
checking for netinet6/nd6.h... no
checking for LIBYANG (libyang >= 0.16.105)... yes
checking for struct lyd_node.priv... yes
checking for ZEROMQ (libzmq >= 4.0.0)... no
checking for pimd OS support... yes
checking for VRRP OS support... yes
checking whether the RTR Library is compiled with SSH... no
checking for library containing dlopen... none required
checking link.h usability... yes
checking link.h presence... yes
checking for link.h... yes
checking for dlinfo(RTLD_DI_ORIGIN)... no
checking for dlinfo(RTLD_DI_LINKMAP)... no
checking for struct sockaddr_dl... no
checking for struct vifctl... yes
checking for struct mfcctl... yes
checking for struct sioc_sg_req... yes
checking for vifi_t... yes
checking for struct sioc_vif_req... yes
checking for struct igmpmsg... yes
checking for struct ifaliasreq... no
checking for struct if6_aliasreq... no
checking for struct in6_aliasreq... no
checking for struct nd_opt_adv_interval... yes
checking for struct nd_opt_homeagent_info... no
checking for struct nd_opt_adv_interval... (cached) yes
checking for struct nd_opt_rdnss... no
checking for struct nd_opt_dnssl... no
checking for struct sockaddr.sa_len... no
checking for struct sockaddr_in.sin_len... no
checking for struct sockaddr_un.sun_len... no
checking for struct sockaddr_dl.sdl_len... no
checking for struct if6_aliasreq.ifra_lifetime... no
checking for struct nd_opt_adv_interval.nd_opt_ai_type... no
checking for struct in_pktinfo... yes
checking for struct icmphdr... yes
checking for IP_PKTINFO... yes
checking for IP_RECVDSTADDR... no
checking for IP_RECVIF... no
checking for SO_BINDANY... no
checking for IP_FREEBIND... yes
checking whether be32enc is declared... no
checking whether be32dec is declared... no
checking whether CLOCK_MONOTONIC is declared... yes
checking for clock_gettime in -lrt... yes
checking for library containing clock_nanosleep... none required
checking for flex... flex
checking lex output file root... lex.yy
checking lex library... -lfl
checking whether yytext is a pointer... yes
checking version of flex... 2.6.4
checking for bison... bison -y
checking version of bison... 3.0.4 - 3.3 or newer
checking whether prctl PR_SET_KEEPCAPS is available... yes
checking sys/capability.h usability... yes
checking sys/capability.h presence... yes
checking for sys/capability.h... yes
checking for cap_init in -lcap... yes
checking for UNWIND (libunwind)... no
checking unwind.h usability... yes
checking unwind.h presence... yes
checking for unwind.h... yes
checking for library containing unw_getcontext... no
checking execinfo.h usability... yes
checking execinfo.h presence... yes
checking for execinfo.h... yes
checking for library containing backtrace... none required
checking for malloc.h... yes
checking for malloc_np.h... no
checking for malloc/malloc.h... no
checking whether mallinfo is available... yes
checking whether malloc_usable_size is available... yes
checking directory to use for state file... /var/run/frr
checking that generated files are newer than configure... done
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/persist/frr-build/python/makefile.py", line 24, in <module>
    mv = MakeReVars(before)
  File "/root/persist/frr-build/python/makevars.py", line 73, in __init__
    super().__init__()
TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
F: failed to configure the sources
```

I tried to execute sudo make topotests or to build the Dockerfile directly, but the error is the same.
I installed frr from source http://docs.frrouting.org/projects/dev-guide/en/latest/building-frr-for-ubuntu1804.html.
Frr is running on a Ubuntu 18.04 64 bit VM on Virtual Box (but i tried to install it on ubuntu 16.04 too).

Comment: Looks like Python 3 code is run on Puthon 2.

Comment: How could i resolve this issue?